# Send Mail based on DateTime field in a Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table called Order. It has fields such as below:

Order:

```
  OrderID   OrderNo   OrderDate    DeliveryDate
 --------- --------- -----------  --------------
     1       O-001   01 Dec 2013   31 Dec 2013
```

I need to send a mail to the user one week before the Delivery Date by default. For example, Consider "thevanvanthiya@yahoo.com" is the mailid, for this mail id only one message such as "6 days to go for the delivery date of the order no. O-001" to be send on Dec 25th 2013. How to do this? I need all your suggestions.

Comment: Please use web or window services

Comment: Scan the table, look for dates 1 week from now, send mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/schedule-a-task)

Set it to run every day at a set time, and execute a console app for example

In the console app:

- Query your table pulling in all orders where current date is 1 week before delivery
- Send email to customer

Comment: I have database in one server and IIS in another server. In which server, I want to make these things?

Comment: It really doesn't matter, you can run the task on what ever server you want so long as you have .Net installed